# Mongoose withTransaction only partially executes

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose's [`session.withTransaction`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html#the-withtransaction-helper) helper is only executing the first write. Here's the code:

```js
const session = await mongoose.startSession();

await session.withTransaction(async () => {
  const member = await Member.create([{
    name: 'John Doe'
    email: 'johndoe@example.com',
  }], { session });

  await User.updateOne({ _id: req.user.id }, { member: member._id }, { session });
});
```

This code creates a new Member in the database, but does not update the User. Isn't the point of a transaction that it only goes through if every operation succeeds? What am I doing wrong; or is this just not possible with Mongoose?

Mongoose: 5.9.26,
Node.js: 14.9.0

Comment: `req.user.id` is probably a string, what type is the `_id` field in the users collection?

Comment: @Joe also a string, I've checked and that's not the issue.

Comment: Try giving the updateOne call a callback that logs the updated documents, so you can see what it matched.

Comment: @Joe hmmm...I'm getting an error, `MongoError: Transaction 1 has been committed.`

Comment: Found this comment in the withTransaction code:  "* IMPORTANT: This method requires the user to return a Promise, all lambdas that do not return a Promise will result in undefined behavior."

Comment: @Joe doesn't an async function always return a promise?

Comment: Apologies, I totally overlooked the async on the callback.

Comment: Hey Ben did you try, use the seesion as param of the closuere `session.withTransaction(async (iSession) => {.... { ISession }})`?

Comment: @Marco that's not in the documentation anywhere, does not work.

Comment: @BenBotvinick can you try adding `.promise()` after in both save and after update methods.

Answer (score 0):

Check if starting the session with the model you are going to base the transaction on helps:

```
const session = await Member.startSession();
```

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/11c68393df88a6f1ea4855e6ac15e54ca9f9d976/src/mongo/db/transaction_participant.cpp#L1712

```
// Cannot change committed transaction but allow retrying commitTransaction command.
uassert(ErrorCodes::TransactionCommitted,
        str::stream() << "Transaction " << requestTxnNumber << " has been committed.",
        cmdName == "commitTransaction" || !o().txnState.isCommitted());
```

Apparently you are trying to commit  a transaction twice. Ensure you don't reuse it. Always end the session:

```
const session = await mongoose.startSession();

try { 
    await session.withTransaction(async () => {...})
} finally {
    await session.endSession()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to write it like this

```
{session :session }
```

Comment: Guess, this won't make a difference. `{ session }` should be the object literal shorthand syntax.

Comment: In mongoose it makes difference I have tried both  ,{ session } doesn't work  .

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have replica setup, transactions requires replica to work.